# Setting up VPN on a VPS

Tags: vpn, vps, xen, point-to-point-protocol

I want set up a VPN in my Xen VPS with one static IP. What I should set in `/etc/pptpd.conf` as `localip` and `remoteip`.

I followed this tutorial: http://freehostinganswers.com/blog/how-to-install-your-own-vpn-server-in-5-mins-pptp-on-centos-redhat-and-ubuntu/.

Comment: Do you have any errors of the issues you are seeing.

Answer (score 0):

The `localip` option represents the IP of your machine on the LAN (at shell, run `ifconfig` to find it). The `remoteip` option is a range (or set) of IPs that are assigned to the clients connecting to your PPTP server (like a DHCP server handing out addresses to hosts on the network). Both the `localip` and `remoteip` options should be set to the same subnet for everything to work.